# Start of with empty View Model MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to create a view which is linked to multiple tables. From what I understand I need to create a View Model and link that to the page.

I get a couple of errors using the below

'PaymentViewModel' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation (related to first error?)

I am new to MVC - come from ASP....Any help is appreciated

```
public class PaymentViewModel
{
    public string playername { get; set; }
    public DateTime dob { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string clubname { get; set; }
    public string productname { get; set; }
    public decimal amount { get; set; }
    public int transactionID { get; set; }
    public bool approved { get; set; }
    public string subtype { get; set; }
    public DateTime subdate { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

I need to start with a blank view as this is the first step to register a player so the information is not in the database.

Below is the code I use to get a populated View.

```
public ActionResult Payment()
{
    DateTime blank = Convert.ToDateTime("01-01-1900");
    var prod = from p in db.Product
        join c in db.Club on p.clubname equals c.clubname
        where p.clubname == "Club1"
        select new PaymentViewModel
        {
            productname = p.prodname,
            clubname = c.clubname,
            playername = c.add1,
            dob = blank,
            phone = c.phone,
            email = c.email,
            transactionID = 0,
            amount = p.amount,
            approved = Convert.ToBoolean("1"),
            subtype = c.city,
            subdate = blank
        };
    return View(prod);
}
```

View

```
@S4C.BAL.PaymentViewModel;
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Player Name</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <b class="control-label col-md-2" style="">Full Name</b>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.playername, new { htmlAttributes = new { autofocus = "autofocus", @maxlength = "25", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.playername, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <br /><br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")</div>

@section Scripts {@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")}
```

Comment: Your view needs `@model S4C.BAL.PaymentViewModel` (but the code in your `Payment()` method will throw another exception because the query creates a collection of `PaymentViewModel` and you passing that to a view expecting a single `PaymentViewModel`

Comment: Thank you Stephen. How do I create a single blank instance of PaymentViewModel?

Comment: In your controller GET method you can just use `return View();` (or better, `return View(new PaymentViewModel());`)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do `approved = Convert.ToBoolean("1")` in your `select` because the whole projection will happen at the database side and it does not know what `Convert.ToBoolean()` is. You need to do this in your view model:

```
public class PaymentViewModel {

    // other properties ...
    public string approved { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved {get {return this.approved == "1" }}
}
```

Also change the first line in your view to this:

```
@model S4C.BAL.PaymentViewModel
```

Comment: Thank you, that has been updated but that is not what I was asking...I need to figure out how to get an empty view model so that I can add a new record.

Comment: @rob Oh just do this `return View(prod.Single())` so it sends one item to your view. That could fail if your query returns nothing.

Comment: @rob see my edit to change first line in your view as well

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am understanding this correctly so please tell me if I'm wrong here.

Sounds like you know how to get a view filled with data from your database and you want to get an empty view without the data filled.  To get an empty view request with just return a view without the model.

```
// Must request with /{Controller}/PaymentEmpty
Public ActionResult PaymentEmpty()
{
    return View("Payment", new PaymentViewModel());
}
```

If you look at the default templates for ASP MVC applications the controller contains actions for Index, Details, Create, Edit and Delete.  Thinking of actions in this manner can help with structuring your requests.  Maybe place Payment into its own controller named PaymentsController and having the actions from the controller follow the default template.